# Convert Gregorian date to Hijri date with location parameter Java

Tags: java, date, date-conversion, hijri

I'm working on mobile app (Java) and found an issue in converting Gregorian date to Hijri date. The issue is that I found a difference in conversion. I'm not getting the correct date due to difference in country dates.

I'm using aladhan API for conversion but I can't find any parameter of location in conversion. It outputs standard conversion.

http://api.aladhan.com/v1/gToH?date=11-04-2021

This must output "27-08-1442" as per location Pakistan. Observed output is "28-08-1442".

Comment: Was aladhan.com supposed to support that? Does the documentation tell?

Comment: I believe that [Time4J](http://www.time4j.net/) and its sister [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) (for Android) support a number of variants of the Hijri calendar. There may be other options too in case the service you have found turns out not to.

Comment: no aladhan does not support date according to location

Comment: So does that observation answer your question? Feel free to post it as an answer to your own question.